# How to improve performance for SQLite database for android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

There are few questions related to this topic on stackoverflow, But I didn't get the proper answer. I have some doubts on performance of flat files, Is it better to use flat files instead of SQLite ?

I took performance statistics for Android `SQLite`.

I have performance statistics for one table which have 21 columns

Can anybody please suggest how to reduce this insertion time.

```
Records  Write time in ms   Read time in ms
1000      67813                   608
1000      66340                   604
1000      64359                   609
10000     679837                  5159
10000     618062                  5110
10000     644638                  5729
10000     646878                  5890
```

`Flat file` have less time rather than `SQLite`

So anybody please suggest me how can i improve this time for SQLite.

I am using simple `database open insert using ContentValues` and database close.

Please suggest me some things how to improve these statistics.

Updated Performance statistics after using below answer.Still i want to increase these performance.

```
Records    Writetime in ms         Readtime in ms   
1000        1645                       530          
1000        2497                       672          
1000        3143                       610          
10000       16356                     5243          
10000       14006                     5122          
10000       13158                     5002          
10000       14828                     5234          
100000      125525                    77622
```

Thanks

Comment: You should post your insertion code if you want to optimize insertion time.

Comment: Flat file and SQLite have different goal in mind, one is storage with bulk retrieval, SQLite is for fast retrieval ( faster than text file in most cases)

Comment: use transactions for large insertions

Comment: also, flat file is nice, but only if you don't need to make queries

Comment: @njzk2 ya i am agree with you point. flat file nice for only read and write.

Comment: Are you opening and closing DB between reads? Opening and closing are very expensive and you should do them just once, before start reading and after finish readind (or writing).

Comment: I am open just only for once. Here after using Leeeeelo's suggestion my performance statistics is very increase. But still i want to decrease these timings.'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe you are inserting 1000 or 10000 using a loop.
Use TRANSACTIONS , it will dramatically reduce the write time. I already encountered such an issue and it reduced the write time in my case from around 30 seconds to about less than 1 second.

Take a look at [this](http://www.android-app-market.com/sqlite-optimization-in-android-programming-sqlite-optimization-in-android-apps.html).

Basically, what you should do is :

```java
db.beginTransaction();
try{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < LENGTH ; i++ ) {
        // execute SQL
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful(); // marks a commit
    }
finally{
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Where i have to use insert query here?

Comment: Here i dnt need to open database and close databse in my code?

Comment: Thanks a lot its really improve my statistics. Can u please suggest me how to reduce read time also using other way.?

Comment: Execute your insert query inside the for loop. Yes of course you should open and close the database. However concerning the read time, I do not know ways to reduce it, hope I helped.

Comment: Ya ur answered helped me a lot u can see results above